# How to retry a task in InternJs until a condition is met

Tags: javascript, intern

I am writing a function that tries to click an element retrying if something wrong happens (staleElement, not visible element etc.). Obviously I don't want it to loop indefinitely in case the element wouldn't be clickable for a bug so I was thinking to insert a counter, but I stepped into a problem:

My test code is

```
var attempt = 0;

var tryClick = function(id, node)//clicks on the element defined by the given data-dojo-id and node(optional)
  {
    return function()
    {
      return this.parent
        .setFindTimeout(30000)
        .setPageLoadTimeout(30000)
        .setExecuteAsyncTimeout(30000)
        .sleep(1000)
        .then(nodeByDId(id, node)) //this just sets the node as context
        .click()
        .end();
    };
  };

var clickByDId = function(id, node)//clicks on the element defined by the given data-dojo-id and node(optional)
  {
    return function()
    {
      var remote = this.parent;
      console.log('clicking ' + id);
        return this.parent
          .then(tryClick(id, node))
          .catch(function()
            {
                if (attempt <= 5)
                {
                  attempt++;
                  console.log('Attempt to click '+ id + ': ' + attempt);
                  return remote
                    .sleep(1000)
                    .then(clickByDId(id, node));
                }
                else
                {
                  attempt = 0;
                  throw 'cannot click element';
                }
            })
          .sleep(1000);
    };
  };
```

I was expecting my test to increment attempt for every catch, but when I run the test like for example

```
  'click':function()
  {
    return this.remote
      .setFindTimeout(30000)
      .setPageLoadTimeout(30000)
      .setExecuteAsyncTimeout(30000)
      .then(clickByDId(notVisibleWidgetId));
  }
```

what I get from logs is

```
clicking notVisibleWidgetId
Attempt to click notVisibleWidgetId: 1
clicking notVisibleWidgetId
Attempt to click notVisibleWidgetId: 1
clicking notVisibleWidgetId
Attempt to click notVisibleWidgetId: 1
clicking notVisibleWidgetId
Attempt to click notVisibleWidgetId: 1
clicking notVisibleWidgetId
Attempt to click notVisibleWidgetId: 1
```

etc.
Could anyone explain to me those results? Shouldn't the catch part increment the variable? Anybody has some idea on how to implement something similar?

Comment: Is 'click' the only test that you're running? What does the entire file containing the 'attempt' variable look like?

Comment: OK so you've already set your `setFindTimeout()` to 30 seconds.

Why continually try to click on the element at all? Why not ask intern to try to find the element to be clicked (this will continually try for 30 seconds as per your code) and if it finds that element within that 30 second limit it will click on it. If not, the test will time out and fail.

This, for me, is the most consistent and sure way to find and click on an element.

I really don't understand the requirement for the constant click attempts?